# Scipy optimize minimize initial guess using SLSQP

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

For some purpose, in part of my code, I want to guess polynom 5th degree, that best fits my data and is nondecreasing in some points.

The sample code is:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as optimize

def make_const(points):
    constr = []
    for point in points:
        c = {'type' : 'ineq', 'fun' : der, 'args' : (point,)}
        constr.append(c)
    return constr

def der(args_pol, bod):
    a, b, c, d, e, f = args_pol
    return (5*a*bod**4 + 4*b*bod**3 + 3*c*bod**2 + 2*d*bod + e)


def squares(args_pol, x, y):
    a, b, c, d, e, f = args_pol
    return ((y-(a*x**5 + b*x**4 + c*x**3 + d*x**2 + e*x + f))**2).sum()  

def ecdf(arr):
    arr = np.array(arr)
    F = [len(arr[arr<=t]) / len(arr) for t in arr]
    return np.array(F)

pH = np.array([8,8,8,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,3,2,2,2,1])
pH = np.sort(pH)
e = ecdf(pH)
ppoints = [ 1.,    2.75,  4.5,   6.25,  8.  ]
constraints1 = make_const(ppoints)

p1 = optimize.minimize(squares, [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                       method = 'SLSQP', args = (pH, e), constraints = constraints1)

p2 = optimize.minimize(squares, [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0],
                       method = 'SLSQP', args = (pH, e), constraints = constraints1)
```

Here `p1` fails to optimize, `p2` terminates succesfully. In addition, if I have no constraints, thus if `ppoints = []`, `p1` termites succesfully while `p2` fails. The message if optimizations fails is always :

```
'Inequality constraints incompatible'
```

The problem is obviously in `initial guess` in `optimize.minimize`. I thougth that parameters of that guess must meet my contraints. But here, initial guess `[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]` meets my contsraints. Can anybody please explain, where is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your initial point satisfies the constraints. But SLSQP works with linearized constraints, and is looking for a search direction that is compatible with all the linearizations ([described here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_quadratic_programming)). Those may end up either incompatible, or poorly compatible in the sense that there is only a tiny range of directions that qualify, and the search fails to find them.

The starting point [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] is not a good one. Consider that at x=8 the contribution of the leading coefficient 1 to the polynomial is `8**5`, and since its gets squared in the objective function, you get about `8**10`. This dwarfs the contribution of lower-order coefficients, which are nonetheless important for satisfying the constraints at points close to 0. So the algorithm is presented with a badly scaled problem when the initial point is all-ones.

Using `np.zeros((6, ))` as a starting point is a better idea; the search succeeds from there. Scaling the initial point as `[7**(d-5) for d in range(6)]` also works but just barely (replacing 7 by 6 or 8 yields another kind of error, "Positive directional derivative for linesearch").

So the summary is: the optimization problem has poor scaling, making the search difficult; and the error message is not very explicit about what actually went wrong.

Besides changing initial point, you can try providing the Jacobians of objective function and constraints (both are important, as the method works with the  Lagrangian).

Comment: Your solution is great, but I had same problems with different datasets. Than I rewrote my code to work with 4th polynomial function, and regardless I have another problems, initial guess problem is solved.